# Create variable from table cells

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

[image: Picture of Table]

I need your help to figure this out.
I have a table (link on top) of prices for typographic company. Let's say, to print business cards. My goal is to create a system where customer can press on a price and confirmation popup will appear with information from table.

For example: I need 500 business cards with Option #1. 
I press on the price 740 and popup window appears with info: "You have ordered **500** business cards with **Option #1** by price **740**.

Manually I can create all variations like  **(row-1, cell-5) + (row-3, cell-1) + (row-3, cell-5)** but this is not an options, even though the logic is right.

I have a table and popup already created and working. All prices are variables and I can change them from my back-end. I need help with combining variables. 
How can I achieve my goal using php?

Comment: You need to include some code, preferable with your own attempts of solving this issue. And perhaps clarify what you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

You need JavaScript to do a popup, not PHP.  You can use PHP to create an array for JavaScript to use to retrieve the values.

In this example I am creating a JavaScript array ($JS) that will have the same values as the displayed table.
In the Table I add buttons to each cell (I use buttons because the default style display is inline-block and their purpose is to be clicked) where when selected will pass the row,column of the table.

```
$JS = 'var cells[';  // initialize JavaScript array
$ndx = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM)){

  echo "
<tr><td><button type="button" onclick="sel($ndx,0)">$row[0]</button></td>
<td><button type="button" onclick="sel($ndx,1)">$row[1]</button></td>
<td><button type="button" onclick="sel($ndx,2)">$row[2]</button></td>
<td><button type="button" onclick="sel($ndx,3)">$row[3]</button></td>
<td><button type="button" onclick="sel($ndx,4)">$row[4]</button></td><tr>";

$JS .= [$ndx[$row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5]][";
$ndx++;

}
echo '</table>'
$JS = substr($JS,0,-1) . ']]';  // trim the trailing `[` and close the array

echo <<<EOT
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$JS
function sel(r,c){
var selected = cells[r,c];
}

 //]]>
</script>
EOT;
```

The main thing I wanted to show in the above is how PHP can pass values to JavaScript.  It is not really needed as you could just pass the value in the `sel($ndx,0,$row[x])` where x is the column number in the table

**But there is a better way that would be more user friendly:** 
This example the user makes selections by checking the check box.  The form is submitted (to same script) for confirmation.

There is a hidden input where name=sub and value=1.  so when the confirm is clicked this can be checked by checking the value of `$_POST['sub']`

```
$sub = intval($_POST['sub']);
if($sub == 1){
  $selections = array();
  foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
    if(substr($key,0,1) == 'c'){
      $row = intval(substr($key,1,1));
      $col = intval(substr($key,2,1));
      $selections[$row][$col] = $val;
    }
  }
// Confirmation (e.g. create popup box) code goes here  
}
```

.

```
echo '<form action="???.php" method="post"><div><table>';

$ndx = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM)){
  echo <<<EOT
<tr><td><div id="d$ndx0"<input type="checkbox" name=\"c$ndx0\" value=\"$row[0]\"/>$row[0]</div></td>
<td><div id="d$ndx1"<input type="checkbox" name=\"c$ndx1\" value=\"$row[1]\"/>$row[1]</div></td>
<td><div id="d$ndx2"<input type="checkbox" name=\"c$ndx2\" value=\"$row[2]\"/>$row[2]</div></td>
<td><div id="d$ndx3"<input type="checkbox" name=\"c$ndx3\" value=\"$row[3]\"/>$row[3]</div></td>
<td><div id="d$ndx4"<input type="checkbox" name=\"c$ndx4\" value=\"$row[4]\"/>$row[4]</div></td>
EOT;
}


echo '</table><input type="submit" value="Confirm Selections"/><input type="hidden" name="sub" value="1"/></div></form>';
```

To style the checked check boxes:
Add an onclick event to each check box

```
<input type="checkbox" name=\"c$ndx0\" value=\"$row[0] onclick=\"chk($ndx0)\" \>
```

Then this JavaScript will change the background color of the div which encapsulates the check box giving visual feedback to the user.

The init() function creates an array for each check box eliminating the `document.getElementById()` each time a check box is checked or unchecked
It also colors the background based on whether the checkbox is checked or not.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[
var div=0;
var c = new Array;
var d = new Array;
toggle = new Array;
toggle[true] = 'checked="checked"';
toggle[false] = '';
bg = new Array;
bg[true] = '#f00';
bg[false] = '#2985EA';

function chk(id){
  d[id].style.backgroundColor=bg[c[id].checked];
}
function init(){
var checked,did;
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (div=0; div<divs.length; div++){
    did = divs[div].getAttribute("id");
    if (did != null){
      if (did.substring(0,1) == "d"){
        var i = did.substring(1,3);
        c[i] = document.getElementById('c' + i);
        d[i] = document.getElementById('d' + i);
        checked = c[i].checked;
        d[i].style.backgroundColor=bg[checked];
      }
    }
  }
}
window.onload = init;
//]]>
</script>
```

Then when the form is submitted for confirmation you can check the selected check boxes by adding `$checked` to each checkbox

```
<td><div id="d$ndx0"<input type="checkbox" name=\"c$ndx0\" value=\"$row[0]\" $checked[$ndx0] />$row[0]</div></td>
```

Then add `$checked["$val"] = 'checked="checked"';` to the $_POST loop

```
$checked = array();
$sub = intval($_POST['sub'];
if($sub == 1){
  foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
    if(substr($key,0,1) == 'c'){
      $row = intval(substr($key,1,1));
      $col = intval(substr($key,2,1));
      $selections[$row][$col] = $val;
      $checked["$val"] = 'checked="checked"';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, modal is not an issue. It is written on JS, but it has option to hold custom php-code. That's why I want to place a part of code inside modal to retrieve info from table.